# Which board game is this token from with a number on the front and "SW" on the back?

Tags: identify-this-game

Please can anyone identify this game? These tokens have fallen out of some box but I can’t remember which one - it’s not any of the ones I’ve checked so far.

[image: front view of token]
[image: rear view of token]

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The token is from [Small World](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/40692/small-world). You can see it in the pictures there.

Here's a photo taken of the Small World instruction manual laid on top of the box lid. Note the illustrations of the coins in the lower right, along with another two 10 point coins from the game laid on top showing front and back.

[image: photo with the rulebook and two coins]

Comment: I've added a photo from my own copy of the game and annotated it.

Comment: @doppelgreener Sorry, I can't see any hand-drawn circle in your picture - so not a single clue on what to look for.